# What model is this bike I can’t find any info

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image: Bianchi]

I’m not sure what model this bike is. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. You have a good start on getting the identification made, by posting a photo. However, the details are too blurry to identify it beyond it being a Bianchi. Photos of the naming on the top tube (the tube you straddle when standing while astride the bike) would be very helpful.  Also, close ups of the rear derailleur, the front derailleur/crankset, the shifters, the wheels/rims, and any identifying names, etc. are very helpful in narrowing this down.  It is the details that will help the most.

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response. So the top tube says via nirone 7 Alu Hydro. The rear derailleur and shifters state shimano claris. And the wheels rims state TEC TRRP 220. Thanks

Comment: Aside - put your chain back on the chain rings before you scratch the finish.

Answer (score 4):

From the Bianchi website, this appears to be a 2021 or earlier Bianchi Via Nirone Claris. This model is also available in 2022 and 2023, but not in that classic Bianchi teal color. The last time that color was offered in the Claris version of this model was in 2021. It could also be a slightly older version as well, but the link to the 2021 version should get you close.

[2021 Bianchi Via Nirone Claris](https://www.bianchi.com/store/us_EN/yqbk1-via-nirone-7-claris-8sp-1.html)

Looking closer, the 2021 model had a different wheel (rim) spec’d than what you noted in your comment. However, the 2020 model did use the rim you noted, but the 2020 model was not shown as being available in the teal primary color (just the 2021 model was). Note that manufacturers will sometimes change components during a production run for various reasons. I still think it is a 2021 model, but a year either way is not significant for this bike. It looks like a nicely-kept entry to mid-level road bike from a well known manufacturer and it is only 2-3 years old at most.